# Setting up VM in Azure from scratch. How to copy files to VM drive preferably by DSC?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, dsc

I have a buch of tools that I copy to destination machine in Azure every time I create a new one. How I do it now

- zip folder with tools
- open powershell session
- use `Copy-Item -toSession`
- unzip

This somewhat works. However, it's not ideal - e.g. update of one tool is not as easy as it should be.

I would like to add this to PowerShell DSC configuration. Tried to find something like that and every `File` resource I found so far uses network shares.

- **Q: Is there any oficial way how to achieve the same result?**
- **Q: If not, any sensible way how to achieve this?** DSC was my first choice, but is not mandatory.

I find this as basic requirement a would expect that this will be one of scenarios that people try to solve.

---

Note1: I use DSC in push mode.

Note2: We were trying ansible to cover whole process (VM creation, LB, NSG, VPN, ..., VM setp - registry, FW, ..)), but found out that not everything in Azure is possible with ansible (IIRC gateways, vpns, ..)

Comment: _"every  `File` resource I found so far uses network shares."_ - why is this a problem? What are you trying to do that doesn't involve a network share?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/fileresource#example

Comment: I'm on dev machine. Imagine I have some PowerShell scripts like `New-AzureRmVM` etc. Then I enable remoting and either copy the files like I wrote in the post or zip & copy/past via RDP. That works too, but doesn't scale at all. You see there is no network share involved.
I don't want to add extra level of configuration if that is not needed (and I hope it is not).

Comment: Sounds like you might need to roll your own DSC resource. If the file contents are small you can probably pass it as a `[string]` property or similar? For larger files you will have to create a method of accessing another external resource (non-file share, e.g. FTP). Check this out for a guide on how to roll your own: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresourceclass